# Negative Solution for Dirac Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The negative solution for the Dirac equation predicted the existence of positron. Can anyone show that basic solution for this?

Comment: "...Can anyone show that basic solution for this?.."
What did you mean?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that? What is it you actually want to know? Also, if you're just asking why there should be negative solutions, maybe look at the [Dirac equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) and its solution, the [Dirac spinor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor) first.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I tried to give an 'intuitive' (or should I say misleading...) explanation. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give you a 'quick and dirty' answer, as I don't feel like I am capable of writing a comprehensive, full derivation.

Of course, what one really needs to show is that the Dirac equation,

$$ (i\hbar \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-mc)\psi=0$$

has solutions that come in pairs with energies $\pm E$. However, there is an easy way to 'understand' that this is to be expected, from the way that Dirac arrived at the equation. The motivation for looking for the Dirac equation was provided by the fact that the Schrödinger equation

$$\left(i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}-H\right)\psi=0$$

is not invariant under general Lorentz transformations. Therefore, Dirac was looking for an equation that would be in accordance with special relativity.

Now, the Schrödinger equation can be interpreted as the operator equivalent of the usual Newtonian relation

$$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V $$

This, by the way, is another way to quickly see that it cannot be expected to apply in the more general setting of special relativity. If you're looking for a relativistic equation, then what better place to start than the famous

$$E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2 $$

However, since we are considering quantum mechanics, we should be working with *operators*. The naive way to go is to simply substitute $p=i\hbar\nabla$ and $E=i\hbar \partial_t$. This would yield the Klein-Gordon equation, which is second order in both time and position. However, it turns out that this is not the right idea, for reasons that are outlined in e.g. Ryder's book on QFT and in [the relevant wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Making_the_Schr.C3.B6dinger_equation_relativistic)

How to proceed? Dirac's idea was to try and find a differential equation that was *first order* in both time and space! This would roughly correspond to the operator-version of

$$E=\pm c\sqrt{m^2c^2+p^2} $$

The precise story of how to convert this equation into the correct equation in terms of operators is not quite trivial (to say the least). **However, assuming that this *is* the right way to go, we can already see that there will be a *symmetry* between positive and negative energy solutions!**

This is, to me, the easiest way to view this matter. I'm sure that someone more capable than me wil also be able to provide a more precise statement involving actually solving the Dirac equation.

Comment: As just-so stories go, this is a good one. ;) (Nitpick: $E = \mathrm{i}\hbar\partial_t$ is *not* a proper operator on the Hilbert space itself (unlike $p = \mathrm{i}\hbar\nabla$). )

Comment: @ACuriousMind I guess *quick and dirty* really applies (although I didn't realize this, could you tell me why it is so?)

Comment: Well, for the 1D Schrödinger eq., the Hilbert space is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so the wavefunctions depend on only 1 coordinate, and that's space/momentum. You cannot define $\partial_t$ on this space, you need to define the *time-dependent wavefunction* in the Schrödinger picture as a function $\mathbb{R} \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where the source now serves as the time-coordinate, and we can take $\partial_t$, but not operating on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but on "paths" in it.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Interesting, thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: The main difference between electron and positron is a charge, not the sign of the energy, because we observe the positive-energy particle with charge opposite to the electron charge and the mass the same as electron mass.

So maybe is better to write about Dirac sea conception as simple argumentation.